# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator iterate and aggregate, issue with aggregation

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I want to perform parallel API calls in iterate mediator then to group the responses using the aggregate mediator. The format is JSON. I am using this code:

```
 [...code in iterate]
<script language="js">var c = mc.getProperty("account");
                                  
                                    print("Value : "+ c );
                                    mc.setProperty("concatValue", c);
                                    mc.setPayloadJSON({"result":{"account" : c}});</script>
                                    
<log>
                 <property expression="json-eval($)" name="JSON-Payload in sequence"/>
              </log>
              

             </sequence>
       

        </target>
     </iterate>
        
    <property name="Aggregated_Responses" scope="default" value = "{}"/>
        
    <aggregate id="it1">
        <completeCondition>
          <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete expression="json-eval($)" enclosingElementProperty="Aggregated_Responses">
             <log>
                 <property expression="json-eval($)" name="JSON-Payload in oncomplete"/>
              </log>
        </onComplete>
   </aggregate>
  <loopback/>
</sequence>
```

The aggregation is not working, if i add loopback isnide the on complete, it will return one json and the second one will print a message in the logs saying that the response was already sent. Can someone help me solve this issue?
And an additional question: do the work inside the iterate is usually done in parallel or in series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Final working solution with some explanation:**

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
<format>
            {               
                "payloadss": [{
"account":"99999999999"
                    
                },{
"account":"6666666666"
                    
                }]
            }
            </format>
<args/>
 </payloadFactory>
<iterate attachPath="json-eval($.payloadss)" expression="json-eval($.payloadss)" 
 id="iterate-over" preservePayload="true" continueParent="false">
<target>
    <sequence>
        <property expression="json-eval($.payloadss.account)" name="accounte" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <call-template target="call_template_a">
            <with-param name="url" value="/getaccount"/>
            <with-param name="method_type" value="get"/>
        </call-template>
            [.. apply error check etc .. ] 
   
        </sequence>
</target>
</iterate>
        [ use same id as the iterate otherwise it wont work ]
         <property name="Aggregated_Responses" scope="default">
            <jsonObject/>
         </property>
     <aggregate description="iterate-over" id="iterate-over">
   <completeCondition timeout="120">
     <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
   </completeCondition>

   [ use expression like this otherwise it wont work, you can even add at the end / 
      your field name if needed ]

<onComplete xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="$body/*[1]" 
   enclosingElementProperty="Aggregated_Responses">

  [ here the json will be as payload, optionnally you can have a script mediator 
  to map the value and change in their names, otherwise you can just return the 
      result and it
     will be aggregated together]

  <property expression="json-eval($)" name="bbbb"/>
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[
  var dataFull = JSON.parse(mc.getProperty('bbbb')); 
            var responseList = [];
        var newJson = JSON.parse("{}");

            for (i = 0; i < dataFull.length; i++) {
       
                item = dataFull[i];
                newJson.newAccountNumber = item.accountNumber;
                        responseList.push(newJson);
            }
            
            mc.setProperty("responseList", JSON.stringify(responseList));
            ]]></script>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>
                            {
                                    "data": $2
                            }

                        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('responseList')"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>

[ the send should be at this level, the code just after will not be executed] 
    <send/>
</onComplete>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `Iterate Mediator` you should have a `Call Mediator` within the iterate flow which does an external call. If not you have to use the `Foreach Mediator` instead.

Iterate Example

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="iterate-aggregate-example" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <property description="countRequests" expression="count(//Account)"
    name="countRequests" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
  <iterate expression="//Account" id="IterateAccountCreate"
sequential="true">
    <target>
      <sequence>
        <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
          <format>
            <echo:echoString xmlns_echo="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
              <in xmlns="">$1</in>
            </echo:echoString>
          </format>
          <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//Account/text()"/>
          </args>
        </payloadFactory>
        <property action="remove" description="TRANSPORT_HEADERS"
          name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
        <property description="OperationName" name="OperationName"
          scope="default" type="STRING" value="echoString"/>
        <header action="remove" name="To" scope="default"/>
        <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:echoString"/>
        <header name="SOAPAction" scope="transport" value="urn:echoString"/>
        <log category="DEBUG" description="***Request***">
          <property expression="$body" name="request"/>
        </log>
        <call>
          <endpoint key="echo"/>
        </call>
        <log category="DEBUG" description="***Response***" separator="***Response***">
          <property expression="$body" name="create_instanties_response"/>
        </log>
      </sequence>
    </target>
  </iterate>
  <aggregate description="" id="IterateAccountCreate">
    <completeCondition timeout="10">
      <messageCount max="{get-property('countRequests')}" min="{get
property('countRequests')}"/>
    </completeCondition>
    <onComplete expression="//ns:echoStringResponse" xmlns_ns="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
      <log description="***aggregated***" separator="***aggregated***">
        <property expression="$body" name="aggregated_body"/>      </log>
    </onComplete>
  </aggregate>
</sequence>
```

Comment: and in this case the responses will be gathered in the aggregate? can you show me an example? also will the calls be in parellel? or one after the other? Thank you

Comment: @user666 I've added an example. By default messages are not processed sequentially. If you want to sequentially process set `sequential=true` in the Iterate Mediator.

Comment: I am working on JSON not SOAP and XML... will the code work on both or just soap xml message? since all the online documentation is talking about SOAP msg... in my case the aggregator is not being triggered at all even if i add a call mediator in the iterator.

Comment: i solved the trigger thing by using the id in the aggregator as it is used in the iterator, however i got an error:  Error evaluating expression: /s11:Envelope/s11:Body/child::*[position()=1] | /s12:Envelope/s12:Body/child::*[position()=1] org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Could not find matching elements to aggregate.   // it seems that JSON is not supported